# List of countries and country dialing codes , country name and country icon objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

need to List of countries name , countries flag icon and country dialing codes in objective c for my IOS Apps . i want show all country name with flag and Country dialing code if any one please provide me because i am new in  ios

Answer (score 3):

You can get name, dialing code, icon , etc in  [Country list](https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all), Call this api, you will have a list of value as **JSON** form

```
 [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"]]
                                         completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
         // ...
       //handle your data here
     }] resume];
```

Read Local `JSON` file

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Country" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
```

**JSON** file url https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7iyUiCdVAr3ZVZKUEF4YVk4TFU/view?usp=sharing

drag file into your application and use it, if you dont want to use api.

Comment: it's public ya personal . it's working always @karthikeyan Thanks

Comment: ya it's help me but i need to ask before implement . it's public ya not @karthikeyan

Comment: it is public api only you can implement it or call it once store it DB, later you access from DB

Comment: or create Json file inside application, store all data manually and access it by using bundle

Comment: Thanks @karthikeyan